# Reverse geocoding with Python/GoogleMaps API: How to parse response

Tags: python, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm attempting to use the Google Maps Geocoding API to find the State associated with a latitude and longitude with a Python script.  I have no trouble getting back a response from the server, but when I do, I'm having trouble extracting the information I need.

```
This is my code:

from pymongo import MongoClient
import googlemaps

client = MongoClient()
turnkey = "MYVERYSECRETAPICODEWOOOOOOOOO"
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=turnkey)

lat = 29
long = -98.4936

#This code runs fine:
geocode = gmaps.reverse_geocode((lat, long))
print(geocode[0]['address_components'])
print("\n")
print(geocode[0]['address_components'][0])
print(geocode[0]['address_components'][0]["types"])

#This Code Is a Problem:
for i in geocode[0]['address_components'][:]:
    print(geocode[0]["address_components"][i])

    if 'administrative_area_level_1' in geocode[0]['address_components'][i]['types'] :
        print(geocode[0]['address_components'][i]['long_name'])
```

The response I receive back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[{'long_name': '6476', 'short_name': '6476', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'East Fm 476', 'short_name': 'E Fm 476', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Pleasanton', 'short_name': 'Pleasanton', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Atascosa County', 'short_name': 'Atascosa County', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Texas', 'short_name': 'TX', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '78064', 'short_name': '78064', 'types': ['postal_code']}]

  File "C:/Users/Pendelluft/Documents/CodeyMcCodeFace/CodeyCode/SNAKESSSSS/SingleQuery.py", line 24, in <module>

    print(geocode[0]["address_components"][i])
{'long_name': '6476', 'short_name': '6476', 'types': ['street_number']}
['street_number']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I don't get is WHY it works fine when I ask it to print geocode[0]['address_components'][0]["types"], but complains I'm treating a list like a dictionary when I try geocode[0]['address_components'][i]['types'] .

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you all so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is with python syntax:

## Code resolved

```
for x in geocode[0]['address_components']:
    print(x)

    if 'administrative_area_level_1' in x['types'] :
        print(x['long_name'])
```

Comment: Oh wow.  I've been staring at that for ages and didn't see that.  Thank you!